# Predicting values using an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, regression

I am looking for a solution to the following problem. I am hoping to use a regression model to predict some values. I can currently use it to predict a single value i.e. the model will predict the y-value for the x-value equal to 10 for example. What I would like to do is use an array as the input value. I am hoping I can get the model to create a new array of predicted values when the second array is used as the input value. Is this possible? I have attached some code hoping that this helps.

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
wspoly = poly_reg.fit_transform(ws)
lin_reg2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg2.fit(wspoly,elec)

plt.figure(figsize = (25,15))
x_grid = np.arange(min(ws), max(ws), 0.1)
x_grid = x_grid.reshape(len(x_grid), 1)
plt.scatter(ws, elec, color = 'red')
plt.plot(x_grid, lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(x_grid)), color = 'blue')

plt.title("Polynomial Regression of Wind Speed & Electricty Generated")
plt.xlabel('Wind Speed (m/s)')
plt.ylabel('Electricity Generated (kWh)')
plt.show()
```

[Output from the above code showing the polynomial regression model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oflEY.png)

```
   prediction = lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[10]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start out by creating a function to return the prediction. The function will look like this.

```
def my_func(x_value):
    # your code goes here
    return y_value
```

Then you can create an array of predictions like this.

```
y_values = [my_func(x) for x in list_of_x_values]
```

Comment: Looks good, I can see where this is going however I am still quite lost as to what goes where. Do I define the input array as 'x_value' and do I place it in the section you marked as '# your code goes here'? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the example I have given above, **list_of_x_values** is your input array and **y_values** is a corresponding list of output values. **# your code goes here** is whatever you are currently doing to generate a prediction (y_value) from a single input value (x_value).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know we're getting closer to solving it but I have a few more issues regarding syntax which and i'm not sure what the actual problem is. Am i able to attach an image to a comment to update you on the code?